# C# Start external process and keep it running

Tags: c#, perl, process, console

I am starting process of Perl console like that:

```
Process proc= new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = PerlPath;
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "some parameters";
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
proc.Start();
proc.WaitForExit();
```

This code starts process, but after process is done, it's terminated. 
Can I run this console and keep it alive, and if I need, send to the console some arguments and something like Enter confirm?

Thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I run this console and keep it alive

Yes you can. Go in a while loop, with Thread.Sleep(...);

> if I need, send to the console some arguments and something like Enter confirm

Yes you can. Take a look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardinput.aspx)